# Transform JSON Array PHP [] to {}

Tags: php, arrays, json

I receive array format:

```
[
    {"value-1": "azerty", "value-2": "azerty"},
    {"value-1": "azerty", "value-2": "azerty"}
]
```

and I wish convert this to format:

```
{
    "value-1": ["azerty", "azerty"],
    "value-2": ["azerty", "azerty"],
}
```

Which method will you use for this conversion in PHP ? Thanks

Comment: What did you try ?

Comment: [`array_keys`](http://php.net/array_keys) on first row, [`array_column`](http://php.net/array_column) to assemble the subarrays.

Comment: Not really clear when you have four items with the same value.

Comment: The logical way would be to json_decode and then array_merge. What exactly is needed is up to you to test

Comment: I am trying to change the format of my JSON array. Values ​​are present as an example.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can collect all keys with `foreach` like this:

```
$data = json_decode($json,true);
$newArr = [];
foreach ($data as $item) {
    foreach ($item as $key=>$value) {
        $newArr[$key][] = $value;
    }
}

echo json_encode($newArr);
```